# Type hint decorator for sync & async functions

Tags: python, python-decorators, type-hinting

How can I type hint decorator that is meant to be used for both sync & async functions?
I've tried something like below, but `mypy` raises errors:

```py
x/decorator.py:130: error: Incompatible types in "await" (actual type "Union[Awaitable[Any], R]", expected type "Awaitable[Any]")  [misc]
x/decorator.py:136: error: Incompatible return value type (got "Union[Awaitable[Any], R]", expected "R")  [return-value]
```

```py
def log_execution_time(foo: Callable[P, AR | R]) -> Callable[P, AR | R]:
    module: Any = inspect.getmodule(foo)
    module_spec: Any = module.__spec__ if module else None
    module_name: str = module_spec.name if module_spec else foo.__module__  # noqa

    @contextmanager
    def log_timing():
        start = time()
        try:
            yield
        finally:
            exec_time_ms = (time() - start) * 1000
            STATS_CLIENT.timing(
                metric_key.FUNCTION_TIMING.format(module_name, foo.__name__),
                exec_time_ms,
            )

    async def async_inner(*args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> R:
        with log_timing():
            result = await foo(*args, **kwargs)  <- error
        return result

    def sync_inner(*args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> R:
        with log_timing():
            result = foo(*args, **kwargs)
        return result  <- error

    if inspect.iscoroutinefunction(foo):
        return wraps(foo)(async_inner)
    return wraps(foo)(sync_inner)
```

I know there's a trick like this:

```py
    if inspect.iscoroutinefunction(foo):
        async_inner: foo  # type: ignore[no-redef, valid-type]
        return wraps(foo)(async_inner)
    sync_inner: foo  # type: ignore[no-redef, valid-type]
    return wraps(foo)(sync_inner)
```

But I was hoping that there's a way to properly type hint this.

I'm on python 3.10.10.

PS. I forgot to say that it's important that PyCharm picks it up & suggests proper types.

Comment: Please provide an actual [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you have a concrete error message that you want to debug.

Comment: The simplest way is to use [`typing.cast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.cast) when calling the actual function inside the inner wrapper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Say you want to write a function decorator that performs *some* actions before and/or after the actual function call. Let's call that surrounding context `my_context`. If you want the decorator to be applicable to both asynchronous and regular functions, you'll need to accommodate both types in it.

How can we properly annotate it to ensure type safety and consistency, while also retaining all possible type information of the wrapped function?

Here is the cleanest solution I could come up with:

```py
from collections.abc import Awaitable, Callable
from functools import wraps
from inspect import iscoroutinefunction
from typing import ParamSpec, TypeVar, cast, overload


P = ParamSpec("P")
R = TypeVar("R")


@overload
def decorator(func: Callable[P, Awaitable[R]]) -> Callable[P, Awaitable[R]]: ...


@overload
def decorator(func: Callable[P, R]) -> Callable[P, R]: ...


def decorator(func: Callable[P, R]) -> Callable[P, R] | Callable[P, Awaitable[R]]:
    if iscoroutinefunction(func):
        async def async_inner(*args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> R:
            with my_context():
                result = await cast(Awaitable[R], func(*args, **kwargs))
            return result
        return wraps(func)(async_inner)

    def sync_inner(*args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> R:
        with my_context():
            result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        return result
    return wraps(func)(sync_inner)
```

Apply it like this:

```py
@decorator
def foo(x: str) -> str: ...


@decorator
async def bar(y: int) -> int: ...
```

This passes `mypy --strict` and revealing the types of `foo` and `bar` after decoration shows what we would expect, i.e. `def (x: builtins.str) -> builtins.str` and `def (y: builtins.int) -> typing.Awaitable[builtins.int]` respectively.

#### Details

The problem is that no matter what type guards we apply *outside* of the inner wrapper, they don't carry over to the *inside* of the wrapper. This has been a [long-standing issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/2608) of `mypy`, which is not trivial to deal with.

In our scenario this means any [`inspect.iscoroutinefunction`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.iscoroutinefunction) check done in the decorator but *outside* of the inner wrapper will only narrow the type to something **awaitable** in the scope of the decorator, but is ignored inside the wrapper. (The reason is that assignment to the non-local variable holding the function reference is possible, even after the wrapper definition. See the issue thread for details/examples.)

The [`typing.cast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.cast) is the most straight-forward workaround in my opinion. The [`typing.overload`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.overload)s are a way to deal with the distinction between coroutines and normal functions on the caller's side. But I am curious to see, what other can come up with.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the type hints here. Why do we need an overload—isn't Callable[P, R] → Callable[P, R] strictly more general than Callable[P, Awaitable[R]] → Callable[P, Awaitable[R]]? The latter just instantiates the former with R ← Awaitable[R]. Similarly, I don't understand the union type in the implementation's return type. The output should be Callable[P, R]; we can't go from sync input function to async output function. R will already be Awaitable[?] if func is async. The problem is we can't actually name the return type for async_inner—it's definitely not R.